# module.js 474 throw err

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just installed the nodejs in my laptop and Im not sure how to run a js file in the node. I tried the following command,
       `node C:\Program Files\nodejs\file.js` but it shows this error

```
module.js:474 throw err
```

Anyone has any idea? Im totally a newbie.

Comment: In my case, the problem was that the working directory of the shortcut file that I run node from was the node directory. I removed it so that Windows uses the current directory as the working directory and that fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to install node modules first.

```
cd C:\Program Files\nodejs\
npm install
node file.js
```

Comment: I m having node js but still it showing this error for me...May i know whats the probllem

Comment: Yes, you need node modules for Nodejs run some code, unless your code doesn't use any third-party lib.

Comment: yeah ok.. Thank you

Comment: But when i try to install node modules...It show error like   
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\package.json'
npm WARN nodejs No description
npm WARN nodejs No repository field.
npm WARN nodejs No README data
npm WARN nodejs No license field

Comment: Plz before creat `package.json` by **`npm init`**